# Can Terraform be used as a CICD to build/deploy application code in aws?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, serverless, terraform-provider-aws, cicd

I am planning to do cicd for my AWS-ECS & lambda application, but I am confused about that can I use terraform to run my cicd pipelines for deploying when new code pushes to my git repository. I don't want to use codepiepline but yes Jenkins if require.

If anyone has built this kind of architecture then pls let me know...

Comment: You would use a webhook and not an infrastructure provisioner for this use case.

Comment: Terraform is not a CI/CD platform. it is a tool for managing infrastructure. It can possibly do deployments for you, depending on what your deployment target is, your builds, and the terraform command itself, need to run somewhere, on an actual CI/CD server.

Comment: yes.. Thank You so much for your responses..... we can manage infrastructure by using terraform.. but is there any chances where we can manage application cicd? I just want to know if there are any possibilities...

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get to CI/CD with terraform is with GitHub actions (assuming you keep your terraform config in a git repo) & terraform cloud. This page describes it: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/github-actions

Terraform Cloud is free for up to 5 users as well. I personally do use terraform cloud since you can version your modules / infrastructure & I use jenkins to schedule the builds. I think GitHub actions could be a little simpler but haven't tried yet.

Comment: Thank You for your response... but I wanted to know if there are any possibilities to manage cicd for an application, not for infrastructure...

Comment: @JigishaAraniya if your application is within lambda and you're using terraform to deploy lambda... in this case you are using terraform for infrastructure & your application deployment. The question overall is a little vague as well. There are many tools for code build and deploy such as jenkins, nebula, spinnaker, etc.